# Why doesn't 32-bit Eclipse run in 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-for-android

I installed 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop and the Eclipse Kepler 32-bit version, considering it should support backwards compatibility with 32-bit apps, but it does not. After a lot of attempts nothing worked out like running it from the terminal, reinstalling JDK, etc. Ultimately I installed 64-bit Eclipse, it runs flawlessly, and then I installed ADT-20.0.3 and Android SDK which gives me the error: `unable to find adb version..error 13`, I tried the solutions from googling like adding path in .bashrc file [Environment variable] and permission to to adb directory chmod 777 but it didn't work out. I think I just might have to revert back to the 32-bit version of Eclipse. Please explain why there are so many issues with 64-bit Eclipse not being compatible with 32-bit apps.